# Перевести строку типа char в массив типа int

Tags: c++, файлы, char

Задание : В текстовом файле INPUT.TXT записаны целые числа через пробел, возможно, в несколько строк. За один просмотр файла сформировать список этих чисел. Удалить из списка первый отрицательный элемент, если таковой есть. Полученный список занести в текстовый файл OUTPUT.TXT.
Первую часть **В текстовом файле INPUT.TXT записаны целые числа через пробел, возможно, в несколько строк. За один просмотр файла сформировать список этих чисел** я понимаю как сделать. А вот как потом символы из строки использовать как цифры, чтобы найти отрицательный не могу понять. Уже как только не пробовала( Подскажите,пожалуйста
Вот часть кода, которую уже сделала:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char chisla[50];
    int mas[50];
    ifstream file("INPUT.txt");

    if (!file.is_open())
        cout << "error" << endl;
    else
    {
        while (!file.eof())
        {
            file.getline(chisla, 50);

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                while (chisla[i])
                {
                    mas[i] = mas[i] + (int)(chisla[i] - '0');
                    i++;
                }
            }

            cout << mas << endl;
            ofstream file_1("output.txt");
            file_1 << chisla << endl;
            file_1.close();
        }

        file.close();
    }
}
```

И еще есть ряд ограничений : Запрещено использовать тип данных string, но можно использовать строковые фукнции: strcmp, strcpy, strlen и т.д. Т.е. под запретом только самостоятельный тип данных string. Использовать нужно char*,
чтение из файла организуете путем считывания всей строки с помощью функции getline

Comment: Вам вообще нет никакой необходимости работать со строками. Вы можете из файла считывать числа, используя оператор operator >>, а затем эти числа записать в выходной файл за исключением первого отрицательного числа.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем просто, если можно сложно...

```
vector<int> v;
int i;
. . .
while(file >> i)
{
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

Если открыт файл `out` для записи:

```
bool wasNeg = false;
int i;
while(file >> i)
{
    if (!wasNeg && i < 0) 
    {
        wasNeg = true;
        continue;
    }
    out << i << " ";
}
```

И еще... Не делайте так:

```
while (!file.eof())
```

Эта проверка сработает только после *неудачного* чтения. Лучше так:

```
while(file.getline(...))
```